# power series find values for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac n{2^n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {n^2}{2^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Hi I am in a basic real class and I am confused about the question:

Given the geometric series: $$\frac 1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3...$$ for all $|x|<1$
use results about the power series in this section to find values for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac n{2^n}$ and$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {n^2}{2^n}$ .

All the theorems in the book only deal with power series that contain an X in them...im not sure what to do. What does that geometric series have to do with anything?

Comment: **note all summations go from n=1 to infinity.

Comment: Note: if $x=1/2$, then $x^n = 1/(2^n)$.  So you can first compute sums $\sum n x^n$ and $\sum n^2 x^n$.  Perhaps you can even find these in questions in this very forum!

Comment: Note: I reformatted your question and changed your $x<1$ to $|x|<1$ in your geometric series example.  What you had written ($x<1$) is incorrect, as the formula fails for, say, $x=-2$.  I don't think I changed your formulas anywhere else, though you should check.

Comment: Do you know power series ? I mean since i don't see a solution purely from geometric series. A solution to that answer uses basic power series and geometric series.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say $|x|<1$

Then

$$
*)\,\,\,\,\, \frac 1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} x^n
$$

For $x=\frac{1}{2}$ its obvious that we get 
$$
2=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}
$$

But if we take the derivative of $*$ then we get 
$$
\left (\frac{1}{1-x} \right )'=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}nx^{n-1}
$$

Again for $x=\frac{1}{2}$ we get

$$
4=2\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}n\frac{1}{2^n}
$$

From there we have $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}n\frac{1}{2^n}=2$

Im guessing you can solve the other , but ill just start

$$
\left (\frac{1}{1-x} \right )'=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}nx^{n}
$$

From there we have (for $x\ne 0$)
$$
\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}nx^{n}
$$

Now we get another derivative from both sides and do the same as before