# Use the power series representation for $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$ and show that the $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}=2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

> ***Problem***

Use the power series representation for $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$ and show that the $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}=2$

> ***My attemp***

So i must express the representation for $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{d\left[\frac{1}{(1-x)}\right]}{dx}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}$$

Ok now i have to substitute x for a value (my book says $x=\frac{1}{2}$) but i not getting how he makes $nx^{n-1}=\frac{n}{2^n}$

if i substitute $x=\frac 1 2$ i will get $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(\frac{1}{2})^{n-1} \neq 2$

Comment: Subtle hint: multiply the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}$ by something.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748893/power-series-find-values-for-sum-n-1-infty-frac-n2n-and-sum-n-1

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} x^n &= \frac{1}{1-x} \\ 
\sum_{n \ge 1} n x^{n-1} &= \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} \\ 
\sum_{n \ge 1} n x^n &= \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} \\ 
\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{n}{2^n} = \sum_{n \ge 1} n \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n &= \frac{1/2}{(1-1/2)^2} = 2 
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You need to plug in $x=\frac{1}{2}$ to both sides and isolate the required power series. I can see just by eye-balling it it should equal 2.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I'm not getting yet, can you develop a little more?

Comment: What do you get when you plug in $x=\frac{1}{2}$ into $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$? I can see you already plug into the power series and got $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}$. You just need to do a little algebra to it and get it into the form $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}$ and it should follow immediately.